# .NET Reverse Semaphore?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, semaphore

Perhaps it's too late at night, but I can't think of a nice way to do this.

I've started a bunch of asynchronous downloads, and I want to wait until they all complete before the program terminates. This leads me to believe I should increment something when a download starts, and decrement it when it finishes. But then **how do I wait until the count is 0** again?

Semaphores sort of work in the opposite way in that you block when there are no resources available, not when they're *all* available (blocks when count is 0, rather than non-zero).

Comment: @Ori: Why's that? MSDN says that's a common way of doing it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(VS.71).aspx

Comment: @Mark: Be very careful about using ancient documentation. Your page was the .NET 1.1 version, when we didn't know better. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx.

Comment: @John: Oh. My bad, didn't realize that documentation was dated... Google turned it up. Correct the question? As in fix the code? Well I'm trying to, but if I knew how to do it properly in the first place, I wouldn't have posted the question ;) **Edit:** You deleted your comment... and SO added a comment edit feature within the last 10 seconds... very cool!

Comment: @Mark: learn this lesson, and it will save you weeks of heartache: Google doesn't remove ancient search results. It's a bit more likely to show you .NET 3.5 pages than .NET 1.1, but will still gladly show you outdated, obsolete, or just plain wrong results - simply because it crawled them.

Comment: @John: Yeah... I usually check the dates on articles, but I guess I didn't expect something like that to change. Anyway, good catch. I put it in the constructor for consistency. I'm still a bit concerned that it won't be able to wake up if it exceeds the MaxCount because of the locks... or does WaitOne release the lock?

Comment: @Mark: I edited the title to indicate that you're asking about features of the .NET Framework, and not features of the C# programming language. Also, FYI, on an MSDN article, there's always a panel indicating which version the page applies to. You can click the links to choose which version you want to see. Also, a URL with, for instance, `(VS.71)` indicates an old version. You usually want to remove the `(x)` and get the latest version.

Comment: @John: Thanks for the tip. I guess you're right that this is more about .net than C#.

Comment: Fixed bug that caused it to sleep forever when count exceeded max (as I suspected would happen...). Uses monitors now. Preliminary tests seem to indicate that it works.

Comment: @Mark I don't think the CurrentCount/Increment()/Decrement() are atomic enough. You should use a private field for the CurrentCount property with Interlocked.Exchange for the setter logic, Interlocked.Increment and Interlocked.Decrement for Increment() and Decrement().

Comment: @chakrit: Why not? The whole thing is locked, how can it not be atomic? And I was thinking about `Interlocked.` but that only increments/decrements atomically, but the following logic w/ the events needs to be atomic too, no?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out the CountdownLatch class in this [magazine article.](https://web.archive.org/web/20081003065703/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163427.aspx)

Update: now covered by the framework since version 4.0, [CountdownEvent class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: A fairly awesome article from start to finish.

Comment: @spender - You'd hope so from Joe Duffy!

Comment: That `BoundedBuffer` looks quite useful, but the `CountdownLatch` wasn't quite what I was looking for. I want to be able to Increment it as well (which should clear the signal).

Answer (score 10):

In .NET 4 there is a special type for that purpose [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent(VS.100).aspx).

Or you can build similar thing yourself like this:

```
const int workItemsCount = 10;
// Set remaining work items count to initial work items count
int remainingWorkItems = workItemsCount;

using (var countDownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < workItemsCount; i++)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
                                        {
                                            // Work item body
                                            // At the end signal event
                                            if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref remainingWorkItems) == 0)
                                                countDownEvent.Set();
                                        });
    }
    // Wait for all work items to complete
    countDownEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

Comment: Aw snap...that `CountdownEvent` looked so good until I tried it. It doesn't let you start the count at 0 and increment it because it's already signaled.

Comment: @Mark could you explain the problem with `CountdownEvent` a bit more clearly?  I don't see the problem with it.

Comment: @Jez: It's been over 3 years since I left the comment, but I believe the problem I was having with the `CountdownEvent` is that it fires as soon as it hits 0, and I wanted to start it at 0 and increment as I added items, but not have it fire until it hits 0 again. I think.

Comment: @Mark I wrote quite a small little extension method that calls `.Reset(1)` instead of `.AddCount()` if the current count is 0.  That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like [System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx) might be a pretty good fit:

> Waits for all the elements in the specified array to receive a signal.

Comment: This looks like a viable solution, although it seems a bit needlessly complex... pushing objects onto an array and setting/resetting them individually, when a simple counter ought to do...

Answer (score 4):

Well... you can *snatch* all the semaphore counters on the main thread back in order to *blocks when count is 0, rather than non-zero*.

**REVISED:** Here I assumed 3 things:

- While the program is running, a new download job may start at any time.
- On exiting the program, there will be no more new downloads that needs taken care of.
- On exiting the program, you need to wait for the all the files to finish downloading

So here's my solution, revised:

Initializes the Semaphore with a large enough counter so you never hit the maximum (it could be simply 100 or just 10 depending on your situation):

```
var maxDownloads = 1000;
_semaphore = new Semaphore(0, maxDownloads);
```

Then on each downloads, begins with WaitOne() before starting the download so that in the event of program exiting, no downloads can start.

```
if (_semaphore.WaitOne())
    /* proceeds with downloads */
else
    /* we're terminating */
```

Then on download completion, release one counter (if we had acquired one):

```
finally { _semaphore.Release(1); }
```

And then on the "Exit" event, **consume up all the counters on the Semaphore**:

```
for (var i = 0; i < maxDownloads; i++)
    _semaphore.WaitOne();

// all downloads are finished by this point.
```

...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand. What if I don't know the max number of downloads? And if I put `_semahpore.WaitOne();` *before* I start the download, and the initial count is 0, won't it just wait indefinitely?

Comment: You should add this sentence to your question: "What if I don't know the max number of downloads?"

Comment: @Mark You *should* know the number of async download operations undergoing concurrently in advance of the "blocking" event you want, otherwise if a new download can sprung up in the middle or during the blocking event, you need a whole different and complex system than just a simple semaphore or waithandles. You'll need a combination of them.

Comment: How would a new download spring up during the blocking event? The blocking event occurs just before the program terminates...it waits for the files to finish, and then exits; no new downloads are started during this period. And even if it did, as long as the count didn't hit 0 before this new download started, there wouldn't be a problem, would there? This really makes no sense to me...

Comment: @Mark I'm glad you got it... :)

Comment: It's too bad sempahores don't have a `WaitMany(int)`... that loop just bugs the heck out of me, even if it is insignificantly costly :p

Comment: I'm confused by this. I think it works as advertised if the semaphore count is initialised to maxDownloads, not 0. But the code as presented can't work because the first download would never start; _semaphore.WaitOne() would block indefinitely.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue where i needed to reset a server upon some event, but had to wait for all the open requests to finish before killing it.

I used the [CountdownEvent class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent(v=vs.110).aspx) upon server start to initialize it with 1, and inside each request I do:

```
try
{
    counter.AddCount();
    //do request stuff
}
finally
{
    counter.Signal();
}
```

And upon receiving the ResetEvent i signal the counter once to eliminate the starting 1, and wait for live requests to signal they are done.

```
void OnResetEvent()
{
    counter.Signal();
    counter.Wait();
    ResetServer();
    //counter.Reset(); //if you want to reset everything again.
}
```

Basically you initialize the CountdownEvent with one, so that it's in a non signaled state, and with each AddCount call you are increasing the counter, and with each Signal call you are decreasing it, always staying above 1. In your wait thread you first signal it once to decrease the initial 1 value to 0, and if there are no threads running Wail() will immediately stop blocking, but if there are other threads that are still running, the wait thread will wait until they signal. Watch out, once the counter hits 0, all subsequent AddCount calls will throw an exception, you need to Reset the counter first.

Answer (score 0):

For each thread you start Interlock.Increment a counter. And for each callback on thread finish, Decrement it.

Then do a loop with a Thread.Sleep(10) or something until the count reaches zero.

Comment: Real programs don't Sleep. Only demos do.

Comment: @Henk I think you meant: Real programs don't busy-wait. Only demos do.

Comment: And I have to agree. Sloppy code on my part. I like both @chakrit's and @ssg's solutions. Btw, anyone have information on how the WaitOneNative inside the framwork is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my C# 2.0 implementation of CountdownLatch:

```
public class CountdownLatch
{
    private int m_count;
    private EventWaitHandle m_waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.ManualReset);

    public CountdownLatch()
    {
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        int count = Interlocked.Increment(ref m_count);
        if (count == 1)
        {
            m_waitHandle.Reset();
        }
    }

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        int count = Interlocked.Add(ref m_count, value);
        if (count == value)
        {
            m_waitHandle.Reset();
        }
    }

    public void Decrement()
    {
        int count = Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_count);
        if (m_count == 0)
        {
            m_waitHandle.Set();
        }
        else if (count < 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Count must be greater than or equal to 0");
        }
    }

    public void WaitUntilZero()
    {
        m_waitHandle.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

Comment: This has a race condition. If both Increment() and Decrement() are executed simultaneously in different threads, Decrement() may see the counter reach 0 -- then Increment() runs in its entirety -- then Decrement() continues and sets m_waitHandle despite the counter now being 1.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestions here, this is what I came up with. In addition to waiting until the count is 0, it will sleep if you spawn too many threads (count > max). **Warning:** This is not fully tested.

```
public class ThreadCounter
{
    #region Variables
    private int currentCount, maxCount;
    private ManualResetEvent eqZeroEvent;
    private object instanceLock = new object();
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public int CurrentCount
    {
        get
        {
            return currentCount;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (instanceLock)
            {
                currentCount = value;
                AdjustZeroEvent();
                AdjustMaxEvent();
            }
        }
    }

    public int MaxCount
    {
        get
        {
            return maxCount;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (instanceLock)
            {
                maxCount = value;
                AdjustMaxEvent();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public ThreadCounter() : this(0) { }
    public ThreadCounter(int initialCount) : this(initialCount, int.MaxValue) { }
    public ThreadCounter(int initialCount, int maximumCount)
    {
        currentCount = initialCount;
        maxCount = maximumCount;
        eqZeroEvent = currentCount == 0 ? new ManualResetEvent(true) : new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public void Increment()
    {
        ++CurrentCount;
    }

    public void Decrement()
    {
        --CurrentCount;
    }

    public void WaitUntilZero()
    {
        eqZeroEvent.WaitOne();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private Methods
    private void AdjustZeroEvent()
    {
        if (currentCount == 0) eqZeroEvent.Set();
        else eqZeroEvent.Reset();
    }

    private void AdjustMaxEvent()
    {
        if (currentCount <= maxCount) Monitor.Pulse(instanceLock);
        else do { Monitor.Wait(instanceLock); } while (currentCount > maxCount);
    }
    #endregion
}
```