# Release lock on when X processes are waiting

Tags: c#, .net, windows, synchronization, ipc

I'm working in .Net (C#) and trying to implement a mechanism which will perform a task only when there are X processes that wanting to perform this task concurrently.
If there are less than X processes (yet) that are wanting to perform this task, then the processes should wait until there are X processes that are ready to perform the task concurrently.

I could implement a busy-wait approach with a single Mutex/Shared memroy. But I'm wondering if there is a better approach.  Is there a Windows mechanism that can do what I need to do?

Basically, I will run the same .EXE file in 100+ different processes (and on 6 different App-domains in each process) on one machine (a specification I got, can't change it). And because the creation of the processes is not immediate, I need to implement a mechanism that will run the task only when all the processes are up and ready to work, just to make sure it is running concurrently.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET Reverse Semaphore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965578/net-reverse-semaphore)

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your response. But the answer in the link you posted is for cross-thread synchronization and not for cross-process synchronization.

Comment: So, change it.  Replace the ManualResetEvent with a named EventWaitHandle and use a MemoryMappedFile to share the count.  I seriously doubt that Joe Duffy thinks that running 600 threads spread across processes and appdomains is a good idea.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for you answer, it was a good solution! How can I mark your comment as the solution\right-answer for my question?